# Wordpress sub-domain different theme

Tags: themes

Looking to use a different theme if user views `http://store.website.com` vs the `website.com`. It's just a smaller scale design than the main website.

I tried this code I found online but it doesn't work.

```
add_filter( 'stylesheet', function( $stylesheet ) {

    if ( 'development.farmboy.ca' === DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE )
        return 'store-ipad';

    return $stylesheet;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest [Wordpress multisite](https://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network).  You can either use it with subdomains or sub-directories, there is a bit of a setup but the link has instructions for you.  Once installed you can set different themes for each site.

Comment: Already have main site done tho.

Comment: A regular install can be turned into a network only if using subdomains, it will make the current site the main site of the network.  I believe you will have to deactivate all the plugins, but you can reactivate them once the network installation is complete.  Keep in mind, anything can happen so be safe and backup your data whenever possible.